# Se me rellenan los campos de la bd en orden incorrecto

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, mariadb

Estoy haciendo un registro para una página y este se me hace bien excepto en un gran error, y es que la guarda los datos en campos de la bd que no debe, adjunto captura.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede observar en usuario se pone la contraseña, en contraseña el mail, en mail el usuario y el único correcto (creo que de casualidad) es el nombre.

A continuación adjunto el código empleado.

```
<form action="LogIn/validarRegistro.php" method="post">
    <legend>PAG REGISTRO</legend>

    <div>
        <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
        <input type="text" name="txtNombre" id="nombre" required autofocus placeholder="Nombre">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="Usuario">Usuario</label>
        <input type="text" name="txtUsuario" id="Usuario" required placeholder="Usuario">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="email">email</label>
        <input type="email" name="txtEmail" id="email" required placeholder="email">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="contraseya">Contraseña</label>
        <input type="password" name="txtClave" required placeholder="Contraseña">
    </div>

    <input type="submit" id="btn" value="Registrar">
</form>
```

Validaciones en `php`:

**validarRegistro.php**

```
<?PHP

    include 'usuarioControlador.php';
    include 'ayudas.php';

    session_start();

    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

        if(isset($_POST["txtNombre"]) && isset($_POST["txtUsuario"]) && isset($_POST["txtEmail"]) && isset($_POST["txtClave"])){

        $valorNombre = validar_campo($_POST["txtNombre"]);
        $valorUsuario = validar_campo($_POST["txtUsuario"]);
        $valorContrasenya = validar_campo($_POST["txtClave"]);
        $valorEmail = validar_campo($_POST["txtEmail"]);
        $valorPrivilegio = 2;

            if (usuarioControlador::registrar($valorNombre, $valorUsuario, $valorContrasenya, $valorEmail, $valorPrivilegio)){

                $usuario = usuarioControlador::getUsuario($valorUsuario, $valorContrasenya);

                $_SESSION["usuario"] = array(
                    "id" => $usuario -> getId(),
                    "usuario" => $usuario -> getUsuario(),
                    "email" => $usuario -> getEmail(),
                    "privilegio" => $usuario -> getPrivilegio(),
                    "nombre" => $usuario -> getNombre(),
                );
                header("location:../../admin.php");
            }
        }
    }else{
        header("location:../registro.php?error=1");
    }
?>
```

**usuarioControlador.php**

```
<?PHP

include 'usuarioDAO.php';

class usuarioControlador{

    public function registrar($nombre, $email, $usuario, $contrasenya, $privilegio){
        $obj_usuario = new usuario();
        $obj_usuario -> setNombre($nombre);
        $obj_usuario -> setEmail($email);
        $obj_usuario -> setUsuario($usuario);
        $obj_usuario -> setContrasenya($contrasenya);
        $obj_usuario -> setPrivilegio($privilegio);

        return UsuarioDAO::registrar($obj_usuario);
    }    
}
?>
```

**usuarioDAO.php**

```
<?PHP
include 'conexion.php';
include 'usuario.php';

class UsuarioDAO extends conexion{

    protected static $conexion;

    private static function getConexion(){ 
        self::$conexion = conexion::conectar();
    }

    private static function desconectar(){
        self::$conexion = null;
    }

    public static function registrar($usuario){
        $consulta = "INSERT INTO usuarios_pass(nombre,email,usuario,contrasenya,privilegio) VALUES (:nombre, :email, :usuario, :contrasenya, :privilegio)";

        self::getConexion();

        $resultado = self::$conexion->prepare($consulta);

        $nombre = $usuario -> getNombre();
        $email = $usuario -> getEmail();
        $usu = $usuario->getUsuario();
        $cont = $usuario->getContrasenya();
        $privi = $usuario -> getPrivilegio();
        $resultado->bindParam( ":nombre", $nombre);
        $resultado->bindParam( ":email", $email);
        $resultado->bindParam( ":usuario", $usu);
        $resultado->bindParam( ":contrasenya", $cont);
        $resultado->bindParam( ":privilegio", $privi);

        if($resultado -> execute()){
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tú pides

```
public function registrar($nombre, $email, $usuario, $contrasenya, $privilegio)
```

pero mandas

```
usuarioControlador::registrar($valorNombre, $valorUsuario, $valorContrasenya, $valorEmail, $valorPrivilegio)
```